# Trope for nonlethal force being used in film fight scenes?

Tags: trope

Is there a particular trope identifying drawn out fight scenes in film and TV where the Villain resorts to using wrestling moves vs. the Hero: punches, bear hugs, and body throws, rather than more immediately crippling attacks to vulnerable spots like eyes, throat, or knees you'd expect in a fight to the death?

Lots of examples, two that come to mind are the train fight between Priest and Black Hat in *Priest* and Hannibal King vs. Jarko Grimwood in *Blade: Trinity*.

Comment: Sorry - the question is a bit broad (could apply to martial arts movies as well).

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CombatTropes

Answer (score 6):

[Let's Fight Like Gentlemen](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LetsFightLikeGentlemen) from TV tropes might fit the bill.